# What would be involved in rectifying electricity from a faulty car alternator?

Tags: rectifier, automotive, bridge-rectifier, practical

Disclaimer: Newbe

As I understand things:

- a car "alternator" generates a/c current
- the alternator contains diodes that rectify the current to d/c current
- if one or more diodes fail then the alternator sends a/c current into the wiring causing all kinds of grief

Rather than replacing the alternator what would be involved in wiring a rectifier inline (external to the alternator on the output side) to get rid of the a/c?

Comment: Can’t you buy the voltage regulator as a spare part? That’s the part which does what you described

Comment: From what I understand that used to be true but now they are not discrete. I could be misinformed.

Comment: The connections to the 3-phase (6-rectifier) bridge are internal to the alternator. If you can get in that deep you may as well rebuild the alternator, or most folks would swap it for a rebuilt unit at the parts shop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your point 3, it does not happen like that - if a diode for one phase fails then the other two phases still work but so poorly that the dc charge output is almost non existant. Which leads to a flat battery...

To replace the rectifier you have to get to each of the phase connections which means dismantling the alternator... Can’t be done only on the output terminal...

The voltage regulator is the part that controls the rotor current...